# "bad interpreter: Permission denied" How can I prevent this error?

Tags: shell, centos, python

I want to run program directly such as `./program` without define the interpreter in shell first. so, how can i want to prevent this error?

> bad interpreter: Permission denied

My operating system is redhat - CentOS release 5.6 (Final)

```
root@server [/tmp/mechanize-0.1.7b]# ./functional_tests.py 
-bash: ./functional_tests.py: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Permission denied
root@server [/tmp/mechanize-0.1.7b]#
root@server [/tmp/Python-2.7.1]# ./configure 
-bash: ./configure: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
root@server [/tmp/Python-2.7.1]#
```

Comment: Odd. Off-topic, but ... "have" /bin/sh and it is +x'ed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to execute programs from a partition mounted with the `noexec` option (likely `/tmp`). Either move them to a directory that is mounted with `exec` rights or use

```
mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

(as root) to allow programs to be executed on `/tmp`. You can make this behavior persistent by removing the `noexec` option from `/etc/fstab` or your init scripts.

Comment: still not work `root@server [/tmp/Python-2.7.1]# mount -o remount,exec /tmp
root@server [/tmp/Python-2.7.1]# ./configure 
-bash: ./configure: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
root@server [/tmp/Python-2.7.1]# `

Comment: @Gunslinger_ `/` could be mounted noexec, too. Can you give us the outputs of `mount` and `ls -l /bin/sh`?

Answer (score 2):

Long-shot, but make sure that `/tmp` isn't mounted with the `noexec` mount option. That can give errors like that.